# jQuery issue with $(window).height() and .width() in IE8

Tags: jquery

I am developing some sort of page and I need to make the following code work in IE8:

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
findHeight();
$(window).on('resize', function() {findHeight();});
function findHeight() {
    var windowH = $(window).height() - 20;
    var windowW = $(window).width();
    var windowW_minusMenu = $(window).width() - 290;

    $('.body-type').css({
        'width': windowW,
        'max-height': windowH
    }); 
    $('.cont-right').css({
        'width': windowW_minusMenu 
    });
}
```

});

```
.body-type
```

is just a major content that wraps up everything on the page.

also

```
.cont-right
```

Is a content on the right, which I want to have a certain width, depending on the size of the window.

```
.menu-left
```

Is fixed float left menu on the page.

The problem is that in IE8 it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Please help me with that! Thank you!

Comment: What happens in IE8? An incorrect value? An error? What browsers have you tried it in?

Comment: Remember that jQuery 2.x does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.

Comment: Try adding width as a property rather using it in the style attribute.

Comment: Still didn't solve it.
"What happens in IE8?" - Nothign happens. It just doesn't work. That's it. I don't get any error or anything.